# Java array out bounds can't find the index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, loops

This is an eulers method program and i think i pretty much got it, but i keep getting arrayIndex out of bounds between my x and y arrays and its counter i, I think i know what arrayIndex out of bounds mean but i cant seem to get where the index went out of bounds. Can anyone help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.in;

public class INFINITE_EULER {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static float functionof(float b,float c){
        return (float) ((float) Math.pow(b+0.1, 2)+ Math.pow(c+0.1, 2)); //to return the function of x and y 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(in);
        out.println("Programme to implement Eulers method");
        float h;

        float y[] = new float[100]; //initialize the value of x from 0 to 100
        float x[] = new float[100]; // initialize the value of y from 0 to 100
        int i; //variable i is the counter for the array
        out.println("enter the value of h");
        h = myScanner.nextFloat();
        out.println("Enter the first and second interval");
        x[0]=myScanner.nextFloat(); //take the value of x0
        y[0]=myScanner.nextFloat(); //take the value of y0

        for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i ++);{ // for x0 to x100 
            y[i+1] = y[i] + h * Math.abs(functionof(x[i],y[i])); //do yi+1 = yi + h * function of current x and current y through the loop
            out.print("y");
            out.print(i);
            out.print("=");
            out.print(y[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y[i+1] gets ArrayOutOfBounds exception, as in the end of the loop it will be y[100] (getting 101th element) and y holds only 100 elements.

Comment: Had you checked the stacktrace, you wouldve known: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100`, meaning index 100 doesn't exists in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem:
in

```
  y[i+1] = y[i] + h * Math.abs(functionof(x[i],y[i])); //do yi+1 = yi + h * function of current x    and  current y through the loop
```

when looping

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i ++)
```

which means

```
 for(i=0 to 99) 
 y[i+1] -- > when i=99, you will try to acess y[99+1] i.e, y[100] that doesn't exist
```

EDIT :
change your code to :

```
for(i = 1 ; i < 100 ; i ++){ // for x1 to x99
        y[i] = y[i-1] + h * Math.abs(functionof(x[i-1],y[i-1])); 
        out.print("y");
        out.print(i-1);
        out.print("=");
        out.print(y[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks , i think i got it by reducing i to 99 and x to 101. but it prints only the last value y100 instead of y1 through y100, help?

Comment: its still printing only the last value

Comment: @DamilolaLucasAromiwe - remove the semi colon (;) from this -> `for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i ++);` and use only `for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i ++)`

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped,i wouldnt have figured it out, i got all my values. now i can move on to adam-moultons.